# valgrind/yosemite installation fails "configure"; clang not recognized

Tags: valgrind, configure, clang++, osx-yosemite

A previous installation of valgrind had succeeded but was deleted (by "rm -rf' of every "valgrind" directory found). Reinstallation now fails at the "./configure --prefix=/usr/local" step with the following error message:

".. checking for diff -u... yes
checking for a supported version of gcc... Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
no (6.1.0)
configure: error: please use gcc >= 3.0 or clang >= 2.9 or icc >= 13.0
Richards-MacBook-Air:valgrind richardcramer$"

Here is the compiler situation:

"Richards-MacBook-Air:usr richardcramer$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.0
Thread model: posix
Richards-MacBook-Air:usr richardcramer$"

Answer (score 1):

If you have already ensured you have the latest copy of Valgrind from SVN, then you may need to run the following set of commands to rebuild the configure scripts:

```
# Only if you haven't downloaded the latest SVN trunk of Valgrind
#
# svn co svn://svn.valgrind.org/valgrind/trunk valgrind
# cd valgrind

./autogen.sh
./configure --prefix=/usr/local  # Per your chosen configure option
make -j2
sudo make install
```

At present on modern OS X, a pre-release version of Valgrind is necessary to deliver the best results.

Once Valgrind 3.11.x is released you should be able to go back to packaged releases.